# Have Eclipse open file when project is opened

Tags: eclipse

I have not seen this asked anywhere, so I was wondering if it's possible to configure Eclipse to open a specific file whenever a project is opened. For instance, all of my projects have a /src/main.c file that is the main code I typically edit. It would be fantastic if Eclipse would auto open it.

Does anybody know if this is possible? Thanks.

EDIT:

I should specify that if I'm working in Eclipse, close the project with Eclipse still running, and then re-open the project, I want the /src/main.c file to be opened.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. All you need to do is one time open the file using

File>>open File>>

Then dont close that file let it be open and close eclipse and open eclipse again. you can see that file opened already in eclipse.

Comment: I edited the post to specify I want the file to be opened even when I don't close Eclipse.

Comment: Yes Buddy, It works even in that case also.Open that specific main.c as file open. Then close project and open project it will be there all time.

Comment: It doesn't work that way for me. After opening the project, the file doesn't open. I'm on macOS Sierra and Eclipse Mars.2

Comment: @user1022934 Follow the steps:1.open your project in eclipse.2.Even you opened main.c from project explorer, open it seperately again as file>>openFile option. 3.Close the project you can observe only the project files closed but still the main.c should open still (not main.c from project explorer).4 Now reopnen the project it will be there regardless of project open close.

Comment: Vinoth, thank you for taking the time to help me. Unfortunately it doesn't do that. Whenever I close the project, it closes all files. When I open the project none of the files reopen with it. Oh well, guess I'll have to live with it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you create this file manually? From the first time you create it, just leave it open when you close Eclipse. The next time you start it, the file should open automatically. In fact it will open all files which were open at the end of the previous session.

Comment: I edited the post to specify I want the file to be opened even when I don't close Eclipse. What you say does happen, though.